# Override abstract method return type with concrete type

Tags: c#, types, return, overriding, abstract

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract AbstractSomething foobar {get;}
}

public class B : A
{
    public override ConcreteSomething foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return new ConcreteSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler warns me that the overriding type must match the base type. My concern with returning an AbstractSomething is that I put a requirement on the user to cast the returned value correctly.

What is the nicest approach to implementing my getter? Is it possible to do this without using generics?

Comment: any reason to not use interfaces here?

Comment: If you are using abstract method then First point is that you should define abstract method in derived class.

Comment: Why would you _not_ use generics?

Comment: Why would the user have to cast it? If he has a reference to your `B`, but only knows `A`, because otherwise he would not need the base class, he cannot expect to get a `ConcreteSomething` but only an `AbstractSomething` (that's what the abstract class `A` is promises to give him), so he should not have to cast it at all, and you can return the abstract class in the override getter.

Comment: To add to pascalhein's answer, if your caller is expecting to do something with a class that has more functionality than AbstractSomething, then this is not an appropriate pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to use generics, but it isn't a bad solution:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T:AbstractSomething
{
    public abstract T foobar { get; }
}

public abstract class AbstractSomething
{
}

public class ConcreteSomething : AbstractSomething
{

}

public class B : A<ConcreteSomething>
{
    public override ConcreteSomething foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return new ConcreteSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to do this without using generics?

Nope.  Use generics:

```
public abstract class A<T>
    where T : AbstractSomething
{
    public abstract T foobar { get; }
}

public class B : A<ConcreteSomething>
{
    public override ConcreteSomething foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return new ConcreteSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it using generics, although this does make some things harder to work with:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : AbstractSomething
{
    public abstract T foobar {get;}
}

public class B : A<ConcreteSomething>
{
    public override ConcreteSomething foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return new ConcreteSomething();
        }
    }
}
```